# Android : How to change the status bar color after scrolling fully up and then again make it transparent on start scrolling down

Tags: android, statusbar

Initially, the status bar is transparent.As the user scrolls the recycler view fully up the status bar should become blue and again transparent as the user starts to scroll down.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code

Comment: Look into "Flexible space with Image pattern" https://android.jlelse.eu/creating-the-flexible-space-with-image-pattern-on-android-b5f8908b9921     https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior

Answer (score 0):

you can use **RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener**

> **[RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html)**
>   An OnItemTouchListener allows the application to intercept touch events in progress at the view hierarchy level of the RecyclerView before those touch events are considered for RecyclerView's own scrolling behavior.

**sample code**

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                //scroll up set your status bar blue here
            } else {
                //scroll up set your status bar transparent here
            }
        }
    });
```